# How many independent connection coefficients are there for a given dimensional metric?

Tags: mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I know that Christoffel coefficients are symmetric, so $\Gamma^i_{jk}=\Gamma^i_{kj}$.

I am asked how many dimensions are there for an N-dimensional metric. There are $N$ choices for $i$, $j$ & $k$; half of these are not counted because of the above equality.

So the number of independent connection coefficients are $2^N/2=2^{N-1}$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Too few :) The correct answer is $\frac{N^2(N+1)}{2}$. You have $N$ upper indices and $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ different pairs (given the symmetry) of lower indexes. In 4 dimensional space this is 40.

Comment: Thank you! Found out in the meantime that your result is also confirmed by [this](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/dictionary/25-christoffel-symbol#:~:text=%2D%20in%20a%20four%2Ddimensionnal%20coordinate,get%20only%204x10%20%3D%2040%20distinct). :) Wanna write an answer, or shall I?

Comment: Nice reference. You finally found the answer yourself. Just one comment: $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ comes from the following count: you put 1 as a first lower index, the second lower index can be from 1 to $N$ ($N$ different options). Next, you put 2 as a first lower index, and as a second you can put already only $N-1$ (to get only new options). Next, $N-2$, etc. The total quantity is $N+(N-1)+(N-2)+...+1=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! That makes it clear! How I viewed it: how many independent values are in a symmetric matrix with $N$ rows & $N$ columns. That is also $N(N+1)/2$ I believe.

Comment: Another question of mine in the same topic which you might like (it is similar in style): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060075/how-to-take-algebraic-bianchi-identity-into-account-when-calculating-the-number